# Adding mail queues in large number using laravel

Tags: laravel

I using foreach loop to queue large number of mails in laravel using database driver. For example

```
foreach ($leads as $lead) {
    $mail_to = trim($lead->email, ' ');
    $mail_to = trim($mail_to, urlencode('%A0'));

    if ($mail_to != '' && strpos($mail_to, '@') !== false) {
        $jobs = (new SendBulkEmailToAll($lead, $request->all(), $mail_to, $fields));
        $this->dispatch($jobs);
    }
}
```

server get hangs and throw error when sending large number of mails. Is there a better way to handle this or just increase php max execution time and sit and wait ?

Answer (score 0):

well, you either increase php max execution time, or you can pass the whole $leads collection to the SendBulkEmailToAll job, and do the foreach loop in it, that way you wont have to sit and wait for it to finish, just keep in mind that by default the queue jobs timeout after 90sec, so you gonna have to increase that if its not enough to process all your emails

Comment: how do i send all mails to queue using lead collection from job class